# Performance gain in turning local variables into object attributes

Tags: multithreading, performance, language-agnostic

I have N threads querying a webservice and generating a file, then waiting 30 seconds, then doing it all over again.

I have another N threads opening and reading those files, inserting into a database, removing the files, waiting 100 milliseconds, then doing it all over again.

In all those objects there are a lot of methods with a lot of local variables: integers, strings, arrays, and other framework-specific objects.

Recently we are increasing the number of threads to read those files, because the webservice is returning a lot more data.

What gains can I expect by turning all the local variables into object attributes (instance variables)?
I presume it's not going to be so many instantiations, since that will be done once when the object itself is instantiated.

I'm using Delphi, but I believe it can be answered to any programming language or framework.

Comment: This very likely *is* language/framework dependent. What in the world are "object attributes"?

Comment: @CodyGray, _instance variables_, I presume.

Comment: The performance gain must be equal to the cost of instantiating the variables, multiplied by the number of redundant instantiations. For integers and strings, instantiation cost is negligible. For arrays and framework-specific objects, the cost depends on their size.

Comment: How could instance variables possibly be cheaper than local variables? If they're instance variables, you're going to have to implement some type of concurrency protection (i.e., locking). You don't need that with local variables because they are by definition not shared across multiple threads. With local variables, space can simply be allocated on the stack. That's one or two machine instructions. It doesn't get any faster than that.

Comment: @CodyGray those instance variables will not be shared, so there is no need for concurrency protection.
Only one or two instructions!? Gotta have to find another way to optimize this thing

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there will be a remarkable performance increase if you turn the local variables into object attributes. However, generating a file from one thread, reading it from another one, and then deleting the file, sounds like the real bottleneck. If there is no really good reason to use a file as temporary storage, use a single thread instead of two for querying the webservice and then writing the data to the database.